# How do I rewrite this jQuery more efficiently?

Tags: jquery

How do I rewrite this code to change a class name with jQuery more efficiently?

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').click(function(event) {
      var element = event.currentTarget;
      /* Toggle the setting of the classname attribute */
      element.className = (element.className == 'card') ? 'card flipped' : 'card';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(this).toggleClass('flipped');
```